# Clarification on purpose of style resets

Tags: css, reset

Do CSS resets operate above or beneath subsequent CSS styling changes? In other words, a random example:

If a reset normalizes the  to being Times New Roman and size 12 font across all browsers, but I then apply a custom CSS that makes all of  tags within  bold.

Thus the purpose of a CSS reset is really to impose consistency across browsers on elements that you do not custom style? Please let me know if I'm understanding this correctly.

Thanks in advance for all answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the CSS reset is to help make your page look consistent across all browsers.  Here is a very [detailed article](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/) on the subject by Eric Meyer.

Basically all browsers have different defaults for their CSS presentation, but these defaults are not the same.  The CSS reset file attempts to create a consistent baseline across all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS resets are to standardize the rendering of the HTML elements across different browsers as much as possible. It creates a common ground onto which you can build various styles. The resets are placed before every other stylesheet so the custom style takes effect. However, chances are that the custom styles you have does not cover every single attribute the browser default has on the element, and results in browser inconsistencies.

In your example you have "bold tags", so instead of having just "Times New Roman and size 12 font", you have text in bold, but you haven't specify the `margin` or `line-height` of the element. In the event that different browsers have different interpretation on those styles that are not covered, and you haven't used a CSS reset, you will see the inconsistencies affecting your layout and style.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much answered your own question.  Moreso than resetting fonts like in your example, it also resets margins and paddings to 0.  This helps in structuring your layout as having margins and paddings left over from not using a reset style sheet can throw your layout off etc.

It is there to normalize every element in preparation for your custom styling.  If you do not plan on custom styling then you shouldn't use it.

There is also a newer way of doing this called normalize.css.  It is an alternative to reset stylesheets.  Instead of resetting eveything to 0, it pre-styles everything to a standard that most people in the industry follow to an extent.

To summarize and correct your statement above: "Thus the purpose of a CSS reset is really to impose consistency across browsers on all elements in preparation for custom styling."